# When wouldn't view return id to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC project, I generate a webpage with checkboxes and button sends id and viewmodel to controller. So far everything works except for one client. I get entire list of checkboxes but when sending data to controller, I get an error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The `ID` is correct and exists in database. In what condition wouldn't view send data to controller?

UPDATE: The problem occurs, when viewmodel has a long list of products.

Comment: please add sample code.

Comment: Added codefragments

Comment: thanks . add model `Shop`.and how call view in controller `Action GET Assortment`. ?

Comment: thanks. Ready-made data can be used for better guidance

Comment: in action `post` `Assortment` .what's means `id`.in model not exist.

Comment: `id`.in model? I don't have this code in my controller

Comment: `public Task<IActionResult> Assortment(Guid id, ProductInShopsCheckboxViewModel vm)`

Comment: This `id` comes from url, for example AssortmentCheck/Assortment/ddbd18ce-18ed-409b-a367-b7e63b9b7b73

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223267/discussion-between-a-r-seif-and-kalev).

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, I was sending too much information to the controller with POST(there is a data limit) and this is why I didn't get the data. Fixed my view and everything works